# How to declare variables in Lua programming?

Tags: lua

I am currently working on a simple project using two different languages C++ and Lua, but i am a beginner in Lua. Here are some variables that i have declared in C++:
      ***

```
double words;
      float  divide;
      float  equasion1;
      float  equasion2;
      double equasion3;
      double set;
      int anynumber;
```

---

And i want to declare them in Lua, any help or suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like you should read a tutorial and/or the documentation for lua.

Answer (score 2):

You don't. See https://www.lua.org/pil/2.html for examples. It says "Variables have no predefined types; any variable may contain values of any type"

Answer (score 1):

In some languages (C++ included) variable declaration sets both the type and the scope of the variable. In Lua the type is associated with the value, not with the variable and the variable may store values of any type (see [Types and Values section](https://www.lua.org/pil/2.html)), but you can still declare variables to fix their scope. For example, `local words` will declare a variable `words` to be visible in the current scope (to the end of the block that sets the current scope). See [Local Variables and Blocks](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.2.html) for details.